# Ruby regex group stored in a variable?

Tags: ruby, regex, csv, regex-group

I'm having issues with this regex it doesn't seem to grab the titles (everything after the last '.' ) I've tested the regex on multiple sources and they all seem to grab the correct grouping. Is it something with the scan function that I am doing wrong?

```
##### data.csv file #####
## Web_Sites.Shopping.Newegg,...
## Web_Sites.Shopping.Newegg_Secure,...
## Web_Sites.Shopping.O'Reilly_Books,...
## Web_Sites.Shopping.PackageTrackr,...
#####

## Grab the title from the list
regex = '([\w_-]+)$'

## Open the CSV File
data_file = CSV.open("data.csv", "r")

## Set the file we will append the data.
my_file = File.new("titles.csv", 'a')

## For each line in the data file, get the correct title
data_file.each do |data|
   note = data[0]
   title = note.scan(regex)
   my_file.print "#{note} : #{title}"
end
```

Thank you,
LF4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not giving [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181) a regular expression argument, you're giving it a plain string and the string `'([\w_-]+)$'` probably doesn't appear anywhere in your `note` so `scan` doesn't do anything useful. You want to use the [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html) class to create and store your regular expression:

```
regex = Regexp.new('([\w_-]+)$')
```

Or (thankyou [Kudo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338794/kudu)) you could use one of the regex literal forms:

```
regex = /([\w_-]+)$/
regex = %r{([\w_-]+)$}
```

And then pass that instance of `Rexexp` to `note.scan`:

```
note.scan(regex)
```

Comment: You can also use the standard regex notation, like so: `regex = /([\w_-]+)$/` or like so: `regex = %r{([\w_-]+)$`.